# How to debug TestNG test with gradle command using launch.json in vs code? How can I can give my gradle run command in launch.json?

Tags: gradle, ui-automation, vscode-debugger

I am executing my test cases by hitting gradle command with some parameter in the terminal.
My requirement is to put this command in launch.json so that I can debug the test.

I did it using node.js but don't have any idea how can I do in Java, TestNg and Gradle